# Create a folder in vc++ 6.0

Tags: visual-c++

In our project, I need to create a folder where we have to generate/copy the text file. I am using CreateDirectory() of the C++ but it throws the compilation error. please help me so I can fix it as soon as possible.

Comment: Do you have a sample of the code that doesn't compile, with the exact compilation error?

Comment: Hi Gil, I find the help and system is able to create a directory. Now I use the system() where I pass the directory path with mkdir command. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/179249/Creating-directory-in-vc  Try this link